# How to match processing time with reception time in c++ multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, real-time

I'm writing a c++ application, in which I'll receive 4096 bytes of data for every 0.5 seconds. This is processed and the output will be sent to some other application. Processing each set of data is taking nearly 2 seconds.
This is how exactly I'm doing this.
In my main function, I'm receiving the data and pushing it into a vector.
I've created a thread, which will always process the first element and deletes it immediately after processing. Below is the simulation of my application receiving part.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;

struct Student{
    int id;
    int age;
};
vector<Student> dustBin;
pthread_mutex_t lock1;
bool isEven=true;

void *processData(void* arg){
    Student st1;
    while(true)
    {
        if(dustBin.size())
        {       
            printf("front: %d\tSize: %d\n",dustBin.front(),dustBin.size());
            st1 = dustBin.front();
            cout << "Currently Processing ID "<<st1.id<<endl;
            sleep(2);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
            dustBin.erase(dustBin.begin());
            cout<<"Deleted"<<endl;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t ptid;
    Student st;
    dustBin.clear();
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&ptid, NULL, &processData, NULL);

    while(true)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<4096; i++)
        {
            st.id = i+1;
            st.age = i+2;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
            dustBin.push_back(st);
            printf("Pushed: %d\n",st.id);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
            usleep(500000);
        }
    }

    pthread_join(ptid, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock1);
}
```

The output of this code is
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt09W.jpg)

In the output image posted here, you can observe the exact sequence of the processing. It is processing only one item for every 4 insertions.

> ```
>         Note that the reception time of data <<< processing time.
> ```

Because of this reason, my input buffer is growing very rapidly. And one more thing is that as the main thread and the processData thread are using a mutex, they are dependent on each other for the lock to release. Because of this reason my incoming buffer is getting locked sometimes leading to data misses. Please, someone, suggest to me how to handle this or suggest me some method to do.

Thanks & Regards

Vamsi

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205364/discussion-on-question-by-siddhani-vamsi-sai-kumar-how-to-match-processing-time).

Answer (score 0):

**Undefined behavior**

When you read data, you must lock before getting the `size`.

**Busy waiting**

You should always avoid tight loop that does nothing. Here if `dustBin` is empty, you will immediately check it against forever which will use 100% of that core and slow down everything else, drain the laptop battery and make it hotter than it should be. **Very bad idea to write such code!**

**Learn multithreading first**

You should read a book or 2 on multithreading. Doing multithreading right is hard and almost impossible without taking time to learn it properly. **C++ Concurrency in Action** is highly recommended for standard C++ multithreading.

**Condition variable**

Usually you will use a condition variable or some sort of event to tell the consumer thread when data is added so it does not have to wake up uselessly to check if it is the case.

Since you have a typical producer/consumer, you should be able to find lot of information on how to do it or special containers or other constructs that will help implement your code.

**Output**

Your `printf` and `cout` stuff will have an impact on the performance and since some are inside a lock and other not, you will probably get an improperly formatted output. If you really need output, a third thread might be a better option. In any case, you want to minimize the time you have a lock so formatting into a temporary buffer might be a good idea too.

By the way, standard output is relatively slow and it is perfectly possible that it might even be the reason why you are not able to process rapidly all data.

**Processing rate**

Obviously if you are able to produce 4096 bytes of data every 0.5 second but need 2 seconds to process that data, you have a serious problem.

You should really think about what you want to do in such case before asking a question here as without that information, we are making guess about possible solutions.

Here are some possibilities:

- Slow down the producer. Obviously, this does not work if you get data in real time.
- Optimize the consumer (better algorithms, better hardware, optimal parallelism…)
- Skip some data

Obviously for performance problems, you should use a profiler to know were you lost your time. Once you know that, you will have a better idea where to check to improve you code.

Taking 2 seconds to process the data is really slow but we cannot help you since we have no idea of what your code is doing.

For example, if you add the data into a database and it is not able to follow up, you might want to batch multiple insert into a single command to reduce the overhead of communicating with the database over the network.

Another example, would be if you append the data to a file, you might want to keep the file open and accumulate some data before doing each write.

**Container**

A vector would not be a good choice if you remove item from the head one by one and it size become somewhat large (say more than 100 small items) as every other item need to be moved every time.

In addition to changing the container as suggested in a comment, another possibility would be to use 2 vectors and swap them. That way, you will be able to reduce the number of time you lock the mutex and process many item without needing a lock.

**How to optimize**

You should accumulate enough data (say 30 seconds), stop accumulating and then test your processing speed with that data. If you cannot process that data in less that about half the time (15 seconds), then you clearly need to improve your processing speed one way or another. One your consumer(s) is (are) fast enough, then you could optimize communication from the producer to the consumer(s).

You have to know if your bottleneck is I/O, database or what and if some part might be done in parallel.

There are probably a lot of optimization that can be done in the code you have not shown...

Comment: Thanks, @Phil1970. I'm not supposed to disclose the details of the algorithms or any other procedures. I can understand that it is very difficult to give best suggestion without knowing full details. As you mentioned above, we receive data in real-time. All this process is to ensure that there are no misses in the incoming data. So we cannot skip some data.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't handle messages fast enough, you have to drop some.

Use a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) of a fixed size.

Then if the provider is faster than the consumer, older entries will be overwritten.

If you cannot skip some data and you cannot process it fast enough, you are doomed.

Answer (score 0):

Create two `const` variables, NBUFFERS and NTHREADS, make them both 8 initially if you have 16 cores and your processing is 4x too slow. Play with these values later.

Create NBUFFERS data buffers, each big enough to hold 4096 samples, In practice, just create a single large buffer and make offsets into it to divide it up.

Start NTHREADS. They will each continuously wait to be told which buffer to process and then they will process it and wait again for another buffer.

In your main program, go into a loop, receiving data. Receive the first 4096 samples into the first buffer and notify the first thread. Receive the second 4096 samples into the second buffer and notify the second thread.

```
buffer = (buffer + 1) % NBUFFERS
thread = (thread + 1) % NTHREADS
```

Rinse and repeat. As you have 8 threads, and data only arrives every 0.5 seconds, each thread will only get a new buffer every 4 seconds but only needs 2 seconds to clear the previous buffer.

Comment: Thanks, @Mark Setchell for the idea, I'll try it and let you know.